# Выборка данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть такая структура базы:
[image: схема данных]

1. Таблица `EMPLOYEE` – сотрудники. Столбец `DOCUMENT` содержит серию и номер паспорта.
2. Таблица `OCCUPATION` – должности.
3. Таблица `DIVISION` – подразделения.
4. Таблица `OCC_DIV` – связь должности и подразделения.
5. Таблица `EMPL_OCC` – связь сотрудников и должностей.

Задача такая:

> 1. Выбрать должности, которые относятся к подразделению «Продажи».
>      Вывести названия должностей.
> 2. Выбрать сотрудников с должностью «Водитель». Вывести ФИО
>      сотрудников и даты приёма на работу.

Предполагаю, что надо использовать `JOIN`, но как его использовать во втором случае, когда между нужными таблицами находятся еще две?
А во втором есть связывающая таблица, опять же не ясно как склеить таблицы?

Comment: А в чем сложность, все связи есть же?

Comment: Последовательно писать join для всех промежуточных таблиц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` — оператор [соединения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0)), принимающий три аргумента: две таблицы и предикат. Следующего вида:

```
<таблицаА> JOIN <таблицаБ> ON <предикатА_Б>
```

...и возвращает он тоже "таблицу" (условно), поэтому можно делать так:

```
(<таблица1> JOIN <таблица2> ON <предикат1>) JOIN <таблица3> ON <предикат12_3>
```

...и если скобки убрать, результат будет таким же, поэтому можно просто писать длинную цепочку `JOIN`'ов без скобок. Есть смысл аккуратно оформить отступы, чтобы было отчётливо видно, какие таблицы сцепляются и как:

```
<таблица1>
  JOIN <таблица2>
    ON <предикат1>
  JOIN <таблица3>
    ON <предикат12_3>
  JOIN <таблица4>
    ON <предикат123_4>
```

---

<sub>Виды соединений (левое, правое, и т. п. ) не учтены для краткости, но синтаксически они отличаются только тем, что у перед ключевым словом `JOIN` будут уточняющие ключевые слова про вид соединения: а-ля `LEFT JOIN`.</sub>